# Authenticate account if email exists after facebook auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

Users can register an account on my site via the default authentication method that requires a username, email and  password.

To allow users to login via facebook, I am using the facebook gem with Omniauth gem.

Existing guides shows me how to authenticate the users up to the point where they can confirm their details ("is your first and last name correct?") before successfully tying the uid and provider to the user record.

However, it does not check if the email is the same.

Does anyone know how to check if the email is the same and if it is, request the user to provide their password to the account already registered on my site either on the same screen for confirming user details or a new screen with just a password field and a message indicating that he needs to confirm he owns an account on my site with the same email facebook provides.

Should this be done on the model or controller layer? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: So you want the password in your database to match the one on Facebook and if it doesn't then you want the user to enter their {Facebook password again | their password for your application} to confirm that they own the email? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Hi tony! Thanks for the quick response and clarification. I've edited my post so the details are less sketchy.